# What is the easy way to submit if isset && isset?

Tags: php, null, isset, isnull

I want to use in a form in one page which is connected to other from and T-SQL where Admin had option to put Date and save it which will check from SQL DB is the DATE Submit then show Date or is that date not Submit use another isset to check value and show it in the same page after $_POST.

The concept looks like :

```
isset (Employ Join Date) && isset (Entry Date)
   return Employ Join Date

!isset(Employ Join Date) && isset (Entry Date)
   return Entry Date

!isset (Employ Join Date) && !isset (Entry Date)
   return NULL 
isset (Employ Join Date) && !isset (Entry Date)
   return Employ Join Date
```

This will provide the result of How long Employ should work for that imagine company.

If so then do something and if it is not filled, do something else. I don't understand why it always says that it isset && !isset. 
What is missing or wrong?

Comment: I dont understand

Comment: Why not `if(isset(a)) { a stuff } else if(isset(b) { b stuff}`?

Comment: Till yet from the concept I've this if(isset($_POST[employ_join_date] && $_POST[entry_date] == "")
   {
    echo 'emply_join_date';
   }

Comment: isset returns true if the value = '', so check value is empty or not

Comment: @masivuye-cokile did you understand now?

Comment: yes now i do understand u

Answer (score 0):

Till yet from the concept I've this :

```
if(isset($_POST[employ_join_date] && isset($_POST[entry_date] == "")) 
 echo 'employ_join_date';
```